# A particular key not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, printing, hardware

One of my key character "v" is not working. It does not print with any combination: "ctrl + v", "caps lock + v", "fn +  v". Now currently I am using onboard for printing keyboard character "v" But I want to use different combination of key such as "alt + 9" to print it. I have checked slow key from uniersal access and it is turned off. I think it is a hardware  problem so what to do?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me, to confirm there is no problem with your Ubuntu I'd suggest plugging in a different keyboard (ps2, usb etc) and see if you have the same problem.  Next I'd suggest using a different OS (to confirm it's not a config issue in Ubuntu), which you can do (if Ubuntu is your only installed OS with the use of a 'live' system, eg. install media using 'try ubuntu' or whatever it is). If it works with external/other keyboard okay, but does not work using a 'live' system - I'd suggest it's a bad keyboard needing replacement.

Comment: So there is no way to use alternative combination to print the character?

Comment: It is possible to remap keys in linux (`xmodmap` etc), but it is not easy.

Comment: Well, you can enter a `v` as a Unicode sequence: Hit `CTRL+SHIFT` simultaneously (an underlined `u` should appear) and then enter `0056` for a capital `V` or `0076` for a lowercase `v`. But that's _very_ cumbersome, especially it won't help for the _paste_ shortcut CTRL-V.

Comment: This may be helpful - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts  (*text entry shortcuts section - only instead of an email address, you want the 'v' character, though the 'replacing keys with other keys' could better suit your need*)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/users/504066/perlduck  @PerlDuck I was unaware of this solution. Thanks! But, I will also try to use some other fixes.